# Angular ngModel checks all checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

Trying to check/uncheck all children checkboxes using ngModel and all checkboxes are checked, but also trying to check alone children and all checkboxes are always checked;

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="myVar1" (change)="myVar1 = !myVar1" /> Parent
  </div>
  <ul>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myVar1" /> Child1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myVar1" /> Child2
  </ul>
```

Tried using [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" property and it results with the same behaviour - all checkboxes are checked;

```
 <div>
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="myVar2" (change)="myVar2 = !myVar2" /> Parent
  </div>
  <ul>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myVar2" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" /> Child1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myVar2" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" /> Child2
  </ul>
```

How to make every child checkbox standalone?
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xj3syg)

Comment: your child checkboxes use the same value as parent, myVar1 or myVar2, which should be like myChild1, myChild2, and when click the parent checkbox, create a function that make all the children checkboxes 'checked'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `[(ngModel)]` for child and parent which makes the child checked as soon as parent is checked.

You need to have different `[(ngModel)]` for children and use a checked/changed function on parent checkbox to do the check all child i.e set child `ngModel` to `true` or `false`.

EX:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="myVar1" (change)="updateChildSelection($event)" /> Parent
  </div>
  <ul>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myVarChild1" /> Child1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myVarChild2" /> Child2
  </ul>
```

In component:

```
updateChildSelection(event) {
  // set child to true if checked
   if(event.target.checked){
    this.myVarChild1 = true;
    this.myVarChild2 = true
   } else {
   //set child model to false 
   }

}
```