# Angular [(ngModel)] checks all checboxes in spite of checked condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a list of checkboxes with accounts. When I try to display the list with various checked/unchecked boolean values `[(ngModel)]` checks/unchecks them all.

```
<tr *ngFor="let accountSetup of this.accountSetups">
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox"
      [(ngModel)]="accountSetup.isAvailable"
      name="accountSetup">{{accountSetup.name}}
      </td>
</tr>
```

I saw this thread [Angular ngModel checks all checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137453/angular-ngmodel-checks-all-checkboxes) but it didn't help me figuring out how to solve this issue in my particular case. Without the `ngModel` the checkboxes are being checked correctly according to the `isAvailable` field, but then there's no communication with my component. How could I solve this?

With `[checked]` isntead of `ngModel` it works fine, checks only those items that have `isAvailable` true. But with `[checked]` I lose binding with my component, so in theory I need `ngModel` but it doesn't work the same way as `[checked]`.

My component looks like this:

```
accountSetups: AccountSetup[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
   this.agreementService.getAgreement(this.agreementId).subscribe(data => {
       this.accountSetups = data.accountSetups;
  }
}
```

Comment: when you are already using ngModel, for two way binding, why do you need use checked ?

Comment: @ShrutikaPatil I've removed the `[checked]`, doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found a solution, the reason it checked/unchecked all of the checkboxes in spite of different boolean values was because it lacked `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`. Now everything works as it should. Thank you all for your answers.